# replaceWith replacing all text instead of null only strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm having some trouble being able to replace the null outputs on my js/jQuery code and it's replacing every text, even if it is valid.

Without the `if (items[z].Office == null) {` statement:
[image]

With the if statement:
[image]

Could anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? All help is highly appreciated.

```js
for(z = 0; z < items.length; z++)
{
  var team = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8"><p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].TeamName + '</p></div><div class="col-sm-4"><p class="office" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Office + '</p></div></div>';
  var single = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8"><p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Title + '</p></div><div class="col-sm-4"><p class="office" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Office + 
'</p></div></div>';

  if (items[z].ApplicationType == 'OneDrive') {
      onedriveSessions++; // Used to pull in Sessions
  }
  if (items[z].Office != 'None' && items[z].TeamName != 'None') {
    switch (items[z].ApplicationType) {
      case "OneDrive":
        $(".onedriveTeams").append(team);       
        break;
  }
  if (items[z].RequestType == 'Single User') {
    switch (items[z].ApplicationType) {
      case "OneDrive":
        $(".onedriveSingles").append(single);
        break;
  }
  if (items[z].Office == null) {
    $(".office").replaceWith("No office");
  }
}
```

Comment: `$(".office")` is a global selector.  It's going to find all office on the page, and replace them with your text.

Comment: How would I go about targetting the class/id that produces the string 'null' only? Thanks for making that clear!

Comment: Rather than inserting the invalid html that you have to fix, fix your insertion to not insert nulls in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<p class="office" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Office + '</p>'
```

This logic here, rather than inserting null, put in a default value.

```
'<p class="office" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + (items[z].Office || 'No office') + '</p>'
```

Then you do not have to fix it after the fact.